# PostgreSQL to Oracle DDL

Tags: oracle, postgresql, migration, identifier

we are using **PostgreSQL** (and we are happy with it!), but due to customer policies we need to run our app on Oracle. Unfortunately our ERD is full of identifier (column names and relationship names) with more than 30 char length (and even Oracle 11g in the 21 st century still cannot digest that, ORA-00972 !).

Do you know any tools that can help to rename automatically long names ?
eg **my_very_long_rel_from_table1_to_table2** to **rel_0123**

Or any other smart recipes ? (No, we not gonna rename everything in 50+ tables)

Similar thread at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194945/migrating-from-postgresql-to-oracle

Thanks for any ideas or feedback
Sven

Comment: I think your customer would appreciate you taking the time to rename the fields manually using naming standards your team approves.  50+ tables is not that much, really.  A human will do a better job at this, and your client will have columns that still make sense and adhere to some naming standard.  Just my 2 cents tho

Comment: What are those policies? "We only use Oracle products"? There's a Oracle Linux (a clone of RedHat Enterprise Linux), which does include PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2):

Excel. And then `sed`.

List all identifiers in schema from Postgres (for example from information_schema). Paste to Excel in column A. Copy to column B. Create a column C which will show identifier name lengths in B. Sort by C. Manually shorten identifiers in B which are longer than 30 until there's none (I'd suggest not doing it automatically, as it would make your database obfuscated). Create column D where D1 would be: concatenate("sed 's/",A1,"/",B1,"/g'").

Copy column D to file "change_columns.sh". Filter Postgres schema through it. Filter your client program source through it.

Introduce a policy that relation names are not longer than 30 characters. Enforce it using for example daily checks of schema in cron.

Ugly as hell.

Answer (score 0):

Weirdly enough I may have just what you need, although the answer is likely a surprise.

Our [PLSQL Obfuscator](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Obfuscators/PLSQLObfuscator.html) is normally used to scramble PLSQL code to make it hard to understand.

One of things it does is rename identifiers.  Normally, it picks "random" names
that are very hard for people to read or copy reliably manually.
However, there's a feature that allows you to control exactly how names are mapped.
(Its all in the docs)
And you could use that to achieve the effect your want pretty easily.

It isn't cranky about the lenght of identifier names, so your naive conversion
to PLSQL with long identifiers won't bother it.  After renaming, you'd want
to make sure the names were all appropriately short.

Answer (score 0):

I used perl and pointed at a pg_dump file. For the name shortening I had something like:

```
sub shorten_name {
    my $name = shift;
    return $name if (length $name <= 30);

    my @abbreviations = ('calculation,calc', 'measure,meas', 'point,pt', ...); 

    my $new_name = $name;
    foreach my $abbr (@abbreviations) {
        my ($f, $r) = split ',', $abbr;
        $new_name =~ s/$f/$r/g;
        last if (length($new_name) <= 30);
    }

    if (length $new_name > 30) {
        warn "Unable to shorten $name\n";
    }
    return $new_name;
}
```

I used an array vs a hash as I wanted to control the order that the shortenings were applied (some abbreviations were much more desirable than others).

'twas a very ugly script but it got the job done in a repeatable fashion.

Other things to look out for are the datatype mappings (especially for data types that oracle doesn't support), domains, `on update` foreign keys, triggers, etc.